# Meaning of SEQUENCE_NEXT_HI_VALUE

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the exact meaning of `SEQUENCE_NEXT_HI_VALUE` in `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES` when I am using `javax.persistence.GenerationType.TABLE` for ID generation?
Apparently, it is not the next plain ID that will be assigned to a new entity by Hibernate.